# How do you get a muted guitar sound in FL Studio?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, guitar, fl-studio

Can the palm-muted effect be added on a guitar loop that I previously made in FL Studio through a plugin?
For instance, is there a way to tweak the velocity of notes to create a muted guitar sound?

If not, please suggest any plugin which can be directly used to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

### Effects

You can apply a *reverse-compression* (a quick Google search will give you many results). This will make the sound more plucky and it will feel like a palm muted sound because the release length (ADSR) of the sample will have a lower volume compared to the other parts of the sample. Now you can apply a low-pass EQ and a little bit of distortion. Now layer this with the un-EQed original plucky sound. Adjust the mix untill you get what you want.

### Plugin

You can use [Guitar Rig](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/guitar/guitar-rig-5-pro/) by Native Instruments. You would easily be able to create the palm muted guitar effect by testing a few amps, EQing the guitar using the in-built EQ and adding a little bit of distortion. It is a very versatile plugin and if you are often dealing with guitars, this plugin will prove to be a boon for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sample, or use EQ and transient shaping to achieve this.